# Расстояние между строками таблицы и их границами. HTML

Tags: html, css, table

Какими средствами в html можно сделать таблицу как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь расстояние не просто между строками, а между границами строк. Каждая строка как отдельный элемент со своей отдельной границей, между которыми видно основной фон.

Comment: во-первых кто вам сказал, что это таблица? во-вторых если это и сделано таблицей, что мешает посмотреть код?

Comment: А зачем тебе использовать таблицы? Это прошлый век. Лучше резиновой версткой (div-оми). Сделай div на него понавешай css отступы(margin) между вложенными объектами и т.д.

Comment: Никто не сказал. Это графический набросок. Я вижу структурированный набор данных расположенных в обособленной группе, для меня это таблица.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Почитал про верстку div'ами. В моем случае это ничем не облегчит задачу, а наоборот. У меня табличные данные с которыми потом предстоит работать - сортировка/вставка/удаление. Таблицей все же проще.

Comment: Наверное потому, что это именно таблица?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Удалось повторить в виде таблицы то, что изображено на картинке в вопросе.
```

```css
body { background-color: #f1f1f1; }

#rootTable {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 550px;
  border-spacing: 2px 5px;
}
#rootTable > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  background-color: white;
}
#rootTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
#rootTable > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  width: 90%;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#rootTable > tbody > tr:hover > td {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.innerTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.innerTable > tbody > tr > td {
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
}
.innerTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  width: 65%;
}
.innerTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
.innerTable > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  width: 15%;
}

.person-name { font-weight: bold; }
.person-info { font-style: italic; }
.dates { text-align: right; }
.price, .paid { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<table id="rootTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>36</td>
<td>
<table class="innerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="person-name">Petya +1111111111</td>
<td class="dates">from 11.06</td>
<td class="price">$100.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="person-info">A good person</td>
<td class="dates">to 15.07</td>
<td class="paid">$110.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>49</td>
<td>
<table class="innerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="person-name">Tanya +222222222</td>
<td class="dates">from 16.06</td>
<td class="price">$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="person-info">A very good person</td>
<td class="dates">to 20.07</td>
<td class="paid">$40.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Изменение ответа.

для создания таких таблиц можно делать вручную или использовать PHP с функцией SWITCH (или CASE. точно не помню)

пример использования HTML + PHP:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .parent {
            padding: 4px;
            width: 60%;
            height: 60px;
            margin: 10px 20% 0 20%;
            background-color: #c3ffff;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .parent > div{
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .child_1{
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
        }


        .child_2{
            width: 80%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$number_of_tables = 10; //измени число на любое другое от 0 до infinite

for ($x = 0; $x < $number_of_tables; $x++) {
    echo "<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child_1'> $x<br>October
    </div>
    <div class= ='child_2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br>
        ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br>
        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>";
}

?>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_1">13 <br>October
    </div>
    <div class="child_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br>
        ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br>
        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если не хочешь вставлять PHP - используй чистый HTML:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 4px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 20% 0 20%;
  background-color: #c3ffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#parent>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.child_1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.child_2 {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">13 <br>October
  </div>
  <div class="child_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">12 <br>October
  </div>
  <div class="child_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

**Примечание:** код не идеальный. просто пример того, что можно сделать в твоем случае

Comment: по-Вашему "*То, что ты ищешь - это*" хоть как-то похоже на рисунок в вопросе?

Comment: @Пашка используй border-radius

Comment: а причем тут php ? вопрос "*как сделать расстояние между границами строк*", а не "*как вывести несколько блоков при помощи php*". Это вопрос css и html и только. По сути вы продублировали код.

Comment: @Alex Автор спросил: "Какими средствами в HTML можно сделать таблицу как на картинке?" . Я решил показать не только само решение вопроса но и варианты создания таблицы. Уверен, ему и многим другим было бы это интересно.

Comment: Вы не правы. Ответ должен содержать решение вопроса, а не "*посторонний код, который возможно кому-то пригодится*". Один из лозунгов SO "Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего". Далее в вопросе нет метки php, а Вы в ответе пишите на php. Следует понимать, что это не форум для мусора. Пожалуйста пройдите [ознакомительный тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), а также почитайте справку [как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). *P.S.: в дублировании кода также смысла нет.*

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста внимательно на отредактированную часть ответа. это пример того каким должен был быть ответ.